# How to animate images while converting images to video in iOS?

Tags: ios, image, animation, video

I want to create one video file from images and that images will animate one after another like Powerpoint Presentation. I am not getting any idea how to do . I have tried in  multiple ways but still not getting any solution. If anyone have any idea then please share . 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to create a video file ultimately rite? Don't you want to show the images with animation only?

Comment: jai I want to create only video file by animating images.

Comment: Please reward people who have helped you and accept answers to your questions. I've seen a few with valid answers that might/should get accepted. Thanks.

Comment: @deepti Have you found any solution? If yes then it would be so generous of you to post your answer.

Comment: @deepti I am also facing same problem , I want create video file by animating images, If you have solved your problem please post answer

Comment: did you find any solution? I am stuck in it :( @deepti

Answer (score 2):

I have one idea.

1) If you directly create video file using some images, it will be move fast.
 To retrieve animation of images, animate the images using `NSTimer` and modifying the angle of images to get animated format and save all those images as per your time to show animation process.

2) Then write all the images to video path and if you want add audio file to video, then add it.

Comment: @Madhu could you please add some code revelent to your suggestion.

Comment: Please add some code as per suggestion facing same problem